# errors with worksheet index

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, syntax-error

I'm trying to use an Excel formula in Excel VBA.

This works as an Excel formula. I'm missing something in VBA to set a variable dptMN.

Here is the formula:
[image: index formula]

```
=INDEX(B1:B88, MATCH(E5, A1:A88, 0))
```

In VBA I'm using:

```
dptNM = Application.WorksheetFunction.INDEX(B1:B88, MATCH(machid, A1:A88, 0))
```

I get

> compile error:
>   syntax error:

on that line

Comment: 1) You have to use `WorksheetFunction.Match` or `Application.Match`. 2) You need to use `Range` for your ranges.

Comment: Your ranges need to be in quotes.

Comment: dptNM = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(myrangeB, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(machid, myrangeA, 0))                   getting : unable to get the match property of the worksheet function

Comment: @jashie see the answer below. Note that code in comments is not readable well. Instead always [edit] your original question if you need to add more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must do it in multiple steps:

1. Match the `MachId`. Note that if it does not match it throws an error so you need error handling here.
2. Use the result `MatchRow` from your match in your `Index` formula.

If you try to do it in one line you will not be able to catch the error.

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'define your worksheet

    Dim MachId As Variant
    MachId = ws.Range("E5").Value

    'first try to match, note it throws an error if it does not match
    Dim MatchRow As Double
    On Error GoTo NO_MATCH
    MatchRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MachId, ws.Range("A1:A88"), 0)
    On Error GoTo 0

    Dim dptNM As Variant
    dptNM = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws.Range("B1:B88"), MatchRow)

    'put your code here eg.
    Debug.Print dptNM 

    Exit Sub
NO_MATCH:
    MsgBox "no match found"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You!  I didn't see it like that.

Comment: You won't have to do it in turns though. Index and Match along with IfError could be combined, even trapping a possible error (and avoiding the `Goto`). +1 =)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way, hoping working through memory would be faster than `Range` object I included an extra `Transpose` to return 1D-arrays (with a dynamic `Range`):

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr1 As Variant, arr2 As Variant
Dim lr As Long, dptNM As Variant

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly

    'Get last used row
    lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    'Get your 1D-arrays
    arr1 = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1:A" & lr).Value)
    arr2 = Application.Transpose(.Range("B1:B" & lr).Value)

    'Get your match
    With Application
        dptNM = .IfError(.Index(arr2, .Match(106, arr1, 0)), "No Result Found")
    End With

End With

End Sub
```

However, you could also opt to go immediately through `Range` object, which could look like:

```
Sub Test()

Dim dptNM As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change accordingly

With Application
    dptNM = .IfError(.Index(ws.Range("B1:B88"), .Match(106, ws.Range("A1:A88"), 0)), "No Result Found")
End With

End Sub
```